# Unmarshaller implcit resolution in spray-client

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json, spray-client

I have a pipeline:

```
import spray.httpx.unmarshalling._
import spray.client.pipelining._
import spray.json._
import MyJsonProtocol._ //which defines a formatter for MyCustomType
import spray.http._
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

val pipeline = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[MyCustomType]
```

Compiler says that he can't `find implicit value for parameter unmarshaller: spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromResponseUnmarshaller[MyCustomType]`

I've done it like in the sample in spray doc [here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-client/).
Why can not it resolve implicits?

**EDIT**
`val pipeline = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[MyCustomType]` is used from method of anonymous class. I figured out that if I declare all my jsonFomats in that anonymous class(I mean stuff that resides in `MyJsonProtocol` I replace to anonymous class) everything works fine.

So question is why this does not work with anonymous classes?

Comment: Did you try adding this: `import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol` (like in the example)

Comment: Yeah, MyJsonProtocol object mixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the type of the value **pipeline**:

```
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[MyCustomType] = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[MyCustomType]
```